# Checking if marker coordinates are in bounds

Tags: angular, location, leaflet, coordinates

I'm using **leaflet** map in Angular 6 application.
I get location info for each item as

`[lat: xx, lng: xx]`

I also get the bounds object which describes what area of map is currently visible. It changes with dragging and zooming. 
The bounds object looks like this:

```
_northEast
    lat: 76.16399261609192
    lng: 111.00585937500001
_southWest
    lat: 18.646245142670608
    lng: -43.76953125
```

I know I could just compare each item *lat* whether it's bigger than *southWest.lat* and smaller than *northEast.lat* and same with *lng*, but **is there any easier and more elegant way to fit it in the bounds?**

And yes, I looked through the leaflet docs before asking this :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need `LatLngBounds.contains(LatLng)`

https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#latlngbounds-contains

Comment: @raulicious: that is nice feedback. Please note that the SO way to thank people is also to _accept_ the answer that helped you solve your problem.