# Flutter maps - check if location is within current bounds

Tags: flutter

In Flutter Google Maps, how can I check if location is within bounds of the current maps view? Other libs provide such functions, like leaflet [Checking if marker coordinates are in bounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53224525/checking-if-marker-coordinates-are-in-bounds)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `getVisibleRegion()` of the `GoogleMapController` to get the `LatLngBounds` and then use the method `contains` of that `LatLngBounds`.

```
Future<bool> _checkIfWithinBounds() async {
GoogleMapController mapController;

var mapBounds = await mapController.getVisibleRegion();
return mapBounds.contains(LatLng(yourLocation.lat, yourLocation.lng ),);
}
```